# Android Studio says "Cannot resolve method" but the project builds correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, methodnotfound

I've just inherited a fairly large Android codebase at work and I've come across a perplexing problem with Android/Android Studio after I've imported the project:

Opening some of the project files, I see a bunch of code highlighted in red  (AS reports "Cannot resolve method XXXX"):

[image]

But the project builds just fine (!):

[image]

The methods in question do not exist AFAICS (I've done a global search for it) and yet, the project builds just fine.

I feel silly asking this but does anyone here know what's going on?

Comment: Not sure what's up with the down votes - would like to know why. Is this not  the right place to ask this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turned out the project was using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html) and those methods were auto-generated and Android Studio does not know how to how to handle them unless you install the [Lombok plugin for Android Studio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin).

Answer (score 3):

Earlier I have same problem **because** Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so clearing `caches will clear the old cache` may be it solve your problem

go to `file menu` and Click `invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you not done a right-click on getPaymentsComponent() and chosen Go->Definition to see where it takes you ?